# What is correct format/syntax of timestamp in offline event data in google analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, timestamp, google-analytics-4, importdata

I have some data from CRM and I wanna use **Offline Event Data in Data Import  of GA 4** to insert CRM's "offline data".
In CSV files that I imported multiple times, All things are good, but although no error found, "timestamp_micros" of events did not appear in results after near 24 hours and time of upload is considered as timestamp of data.

**Is this format for "Timestamp_micros"  is TRUE?
2021-04-08T22:25:09.335541+02:00**

How can I add timestamp dimension on import data offline in Google Analytics 4? Can be done without using GTM?

I expect that timestamp related to each event would appear correctly in results and reports.

Answer (score 0):

That documentation page
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10325025?hl=en#template
gives an example

[image: timestamp]

As you see it's a [Unix time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response

But unfortunately my problem is unsolved. 
**upload time/date** considered as data timestamp, not the timestamp associated with each event in imported CSV file.
It's worth noting that the imported event happened within the last 72 hours.